# Store SQL query result in variable

Tags: mysql, powershell, powershell-4.0

I don't understand why it's so hard to store a query result in a variable.

When I run this script without trying to store the result in a variable I get the correct result. But if I try to store that same value in a variable the value of the variable is `System.Data.DataRow`. I've tried converting it to a string (which crashes the script), `$data_set.Tables[0].Rows[0]`, and `$data_set.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Value"]` but still no luck. Printing the result is not enough, I need to make changes based on the query result.

I want `$max_slide_count = 910980`

```
$slide_id_query = "SELECT MAX(SLIDE_ID) FROM INFOTECHSLIDES.SLIDES;"
try {
        Write-Host "Creating Database Connection"

        #ENABLE MYSQL DRIVER
        [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")

        #CREATE MYSQL CONNECTION
        $connection = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
        $connection.ConnectionString = $connection_string

        #OPEN DB CONNECTION
        Write-Host "Opening Database Connection"
        $connection.Open()

        #RUN MYSQL QUERY
        $command = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand($slide_id_query, $connection)
        $data_adapter = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter($command)
        $data_set = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
        $record_count = $data_adapter.Fill($data_set, "data")

        #STORE RESULT
        $max_slide_count = $data_set.Tables[0]

        $data_set.Tables[0]                   #RETURNS: MAX(SLIDE_ID) : 910980
        Write-Host "Result: $max_slide_count" #RETURNS: System.Data.DataRow

} catch {
        Write-Host "Could not execute MySql Query" $Error[0]
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't return "System.Data.DataRow" - it returns an object that when converted to a string, is represented as s"System.Data.DataRow"

Comment: What do you mean by assigning to a variable ? Is it "$record_count = $data_adapter.Fill($data_set, "data")"  You don't have to assign it that way. The query output will already be filled in your dataset $data_set. What error do u get when you try to read "$data_set"

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Right, so I tried getting the value of that object but I must not be doing it correctly

Comment: "store the result in a variable" ... *how*? For help with something that isn't working you need to *show* us what you tried that didn't work, and how exactly it failed.

Comment: @PrageethSaravanan I don't get an error I get the same `System.Data.DataRow` object. The `$record_count = $data_adapter.Fill($data_set, "data")` was from an example I was following, based on the name I thought that it got the size of the result. Thank you for that information.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I'm sorry, I feel like I am showing what I tried and the results that I got...

Comment: My Query `$slide_id_query = "SELECT MAX(SLIDE_ID) FROM INFOTECHSLIDES.SLIDES;"`  And Sorry I typed the wrong thing in my code, if I say `$data_set.Tables[0]` by itself it returns `MAX(SLIDE_ID) : 910918` not `Write-Host  "$data_set.Tables[0]"`. I want to store the actual result to a variable `$result = 910918`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the item from the row. 
 `$max_slide_count = $data_set.Tables[0].Rows[0].Item("MAX(SLIDE_ID)")`